# jQuery menu doesn't slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why my Accordionmenu won't work?

The menu doesn't slide down.

jQuery:

```
$('.rights li').click(function(){
$('ol.content').slideDown(500); 
    $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
});

$('ol.content').hide();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QEn6x/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ use this

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: <kbd>[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QEn6x/3/)</kbd>

```
$('.rights li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('ol.content').slideDown(500);  
    $(this).siblings().find('ol.content').slideUp('normal');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('ol.content').hide();
```

Comment: You need to close an open menu when clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the URL of de a tag.

Add e.preventDefault() and solved the problem.

```
$('.rights li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ol.content').slideDown(500); 
    $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
});
$('ol.content').hide();
```